# Inkscape doesn't open on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome, inkscape

It starts and appears on system monitor, but it doesn't open any window...

Any solution?

I'm using:
Inkscape 0.48.3.1 r9886 (Mar 29 2012)
Ubuntu 12.04 32bits - using gnome-shell

Answer (score 1):

There should be a hidden directory in your home folder `~/.config/inkscape`, try moving that `inkscape` directory elsewhere and then try restarting Inkscape. If that does not work you can bring back that `inscape` directory under `.config` again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Samik! However, your suggestion didn't work... But I've realised what happened. A iconpack I've installed (MeliaSVG) uses another icon for inkscape. So I've substituted this icon by the real inkscape icon in the iconpack. Then a conflict took place... Now, I've just undo that and inkscape return to work.

Comment: please click the tick box next to your answer to mark this thread as closed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I needed to re-install libgtkmm-2.4.so.1

See  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/1005400 for details